# How to start a progress bar after another one has finished using JSF Primefaces 5.2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, progress-bar

I'm new to JSF and I'm facing some trouble, one of which presented by the question above, that I can't find a solution anywhere.

**My scenario is:**

1. I have a list of progress bars, each one responsible for showing the progress of a method execution (this method contains only a for loop with a *Thread.sleep()* to simulate a task that takes some time and I use this method with all the progress bars).
2. Each progress bar has a button responsible for cancelling the task.
3. There's also a button responsible to start the first "task".

**What I need:**
As soon as I click the start button, I need it to start the first task, hence the first progress bar.
After it has finished, the next task must start, hence the next progress bar.
After the second one has finished, the third task must start, hence the third progress bar, and so on...

**The problem:**
I'm having trouble trying to make the second task start as soon as the first one finishes, and so on. I still couldn't figure out how to make it work.

I can't even remember the things I tried to solve this problem, so now I'm here...

Here is my .xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <br/>
    <p:outputLabel for="botao-iniciar">Iniciar transferências:</p:outputLabel>
    <p:commandButton id="botao-iniciar" onclick="PF('pbAjax-1').start()"
    widgetVar="startButton" value="Iniciar" />
    <br/><br/>
    <p:separator />

    <ui:repeat var="transf" value="#{transferenciaStatusMB.listaTransferencia}">
        <h:panelGrid style="width:100%">
            <p:outputLabel>Transferência ID: #{transf.id}</p:outputLabel>

            <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax-#{transf.id}" ajax="true" 
            value="#{transferenciaStatusMB.getProgresso(transf)}" 
            labelTemplate="{value}%" global="false" interval="1000" >
                <p:ajax event="complete" 
                listener="#{transferenciaStatusMB.onComplete(transf)}" />
            </p:progressBar>

            <p:commandButton widgetVar="cancelButton-#{transf.id}" value="Cancelar" 
            actionListener="#{transferenciaStatusMB.cancelar(transf)}"
            oncomplete="PF('cancelButton-#{transf.id}').disable();" >                       
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:separator />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

And here are the bean's methods used by it:

```
// Simulate task (based on the Primefaces' showcase example): 
public Integer getProgresso(Transferencia transferencia) {
    if(transferencia.getProgresso() == null) {
        transferencia.setProgresso(0);
    } else {
           System.out.printf("Progress Transference ID %d: %d.\n", transferencia.getId(), transferencia.getProgresso());

        if(transferencia.getProgresso() < 100){
            transferencia.setProgresso(
                transferencia.getProgresso() + (int)(Math.random() * 35));

            if(transferencia.getProgresso() > 100) {
                transferencia.setProgresso(100);
            }
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return transferencia.getProgresso();
}

// Cancel a task:
public void cancelar(Transferencia transferencia) {
    transferencia.setProgresso(null);
    System.out.println("Transferencia ID " + transferencia.getId() +" CANCELADA!");
}

// After a task is completed:
public void onComplete(Transferencia transferencia) {
    System.out.println("Transferencia ID " + transferencia.getId() +" FINALIZADA!");
}
```

Comment: You should post source code class `Transferencia.java`. I don't know what  is under the hood.

Comment: Hi, @ĐỗNhưVý ! Transferencia.java is a POJO.